# How do I stop VBA execution interruptions when typing in a different application?

Tags: excel, vba

I write complex VBA apps that automate report creation by running SAP queries and enhancing and combining their results in Excel. These macros run for a few minutes to hours. I found that if I am active in another application like Outlook while the Excel macro is running, my typing in an email can sometimes jump into the spreadsheet and interrupt the macro execution.

Is there a way in VBA to lock out other windows apps from interfering with macro execution in Excel? Could this be related to use of DoEvents in macro loops?

Comment: Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: It may be worth looking at using something like C# or VBScript to do what you want rather than invoking VBA directly from an Excel thread.  That way, you're not executing macros, you're executing external code that is talking to the workbook, it's worth a thought anyway.